# RTL test a button onClick prop

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am following the RTL docs and want to test my button component. I can't seem  get my test to pass for the `onclick`. I have mocked the `onClick` function but I am getting the below error.

[I am following this guide](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/)

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

import Button from "../Button/Button"

const handleClick = jest.fn();

describe('Button', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {

        render(
            <Button
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                buttonText
            </Button>
        )
    })

    it('should render button text', () => {
        const buttonText = "buttonText"
        expect(screen.getByText(buttonText)).toBeInTheDocument()
    })

    it('calls onClick prop when clicked', () => {
        const handleClick = jest.fn();
        const buttonText = "buttonText"
        fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(buttonText))
        expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
})
```

```
import React from "react";

import { PrimaryButton } from "./Button.styles";

const Button = ({ onClick, children }) => (
    <PrimaryButton
        type="button"
        onClick={onClick}
    >
        {children}
    </PrimaryButton>
);

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to be resetting `handleClick` inside the test or else you'll lose reference to the actual click handler mock that you've declared in the higher scope.

```js
it('calls onClick prop when clicked', () => {
  const buttonText = "buttonText"
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(buttonText))
  expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```

You may also need to reset the click count between tests. You can do this with `clearAllMocks`:

```js
afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
})
```

Comment: Oh great thanks. Does the after each, usually sit under the beforeEach?

Comment: It doesn't have to, but I find it clearer if they're next to each other